# How to transform a RGB color to a RGBA one, of prescribed alpha

Tags: colors, julia

I'm working on a ridge plot, with each density filled with a color from a colorscheme.
Namely, I have a function:

```
using ColorSchemes
function get_colors_cmap(cscheme::ColorScheme;  ncolors=11)
    cmap = [(ColorSchemes.hex∘get)(cscheme, k/(ncolors-1)) for k in 0:ncolors-1]       
end 
colors=get_colors_cmap(ColorSchemes.ice; ncolors= 12)
```

and this ridgeplot wih densities filled  with `colors`:

[image]

I want to define another method:

```
function get_colors_cmap(cscheme::ColorScheme, alpha::T;  ncolors=11) where T<:Real
    cmap = [get(cscheme, k/(ncolors-1)) for k in 0:ncolors-1] 
    #How to transform each RGB color from cmap to a RGBA one with given alpha
    #to get
    cmaprgba=...
end
```

such that to be able to change the transparency of each filled density.

Comment: A clean one-line version can be: `gen_RGBA_cscheme(cscheme, alpha;  ncolors=11) = [RGBA(cscheme[t],alpha) for t in range(0.0,1.0; length=ncolors)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use package `Colors` that has an `RGBA` constructor.
You can use vectorization in your code to make it shorter.

```
julia> RGBA.(get.(Ref(ColorSchemes.ice),0:0.2:1.0), 0.66)
6-element Array{RGBA{Float64},1} with eltype RGBA{Float64}:
 RGBA{Float64}(0.015311674355437298,0.02252059388699532,0.07272873735907764,0.66)
 RGBA{Float64}(0.1885572370561371,0.18244321595495852,0.37322757196987777,0.66)
 RGBA{Float64}(0.2443138504548737,0.3677722517524962,0.662711372868709,0.66)
 RGBA{Float64}(0.3221897826221614,0.5869454581955375,0.756147699056641,0.66)
 RGBA{Float64}(0.5507978944105677,0.7960838061951434,0.8381442735434429,0.66)
 RGBA{Float64}(0.9180592960081255,0.991813535883849,0.9928328638314804,0.66)
```